# Solução para while em estrutura HTML

Tags: php, html, pdo, while

Alguém tem uma solução simples para loop while em PHP para a seguinte estrutura HTML?

Basicamente quero que a cada 3 divs haja um `<li>` separando-as para que o slide possa funcionar corretamente, já que cada  `<li>` funciona como "nova página". A [página modelo](http://tecint.com.br/stackoverflow/), se analisarem o código-fonte, está bem completa e de fácil entendimento.

### Código PHP

```
<?php 
$fotosEmpresa = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM imgs_global WHERE TipoImg = ? ORDER BY rand()");                      
$fotosEmpresa->execute(array("QuemSomos")); 
if($fotosEmpresa->rowCount() > 0): ?>
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
        <div class="row">
        <?php while($rowFotoEmpresa = $fotosEmpresa->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)): ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="team-post">
                    <div class="team-gal">
                        <a href="administracao/imagens/quemsomos/imgG/<?php echo $rowFotoEmpresa->NomeImg; ?>" class="zoom">
                            <img alt="" src="administracao/imagens/quemsomos/<?php echo $rowFotoEmpresa->NomeImg; ?>">                          
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>  
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

### Estrutura em HTML

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="team-post">
                    <div class="team-gal">
                        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x378">
                    </div>
                    <h2>John Smith</h2>
                    <span>Webdesigner</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="team-post">
                    <div class="team-gal">
                        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x378">
                    </div>
                    <h2>Mike Smith</h2>
                    <span>Founder of a Company</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="team-post">
                    <div class="team-gal">
                        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x378">
                    </div>
                    <h2>Donald Smith</h2>
                    <span>Development</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="team-post">
                    <div class="team-gal">
                        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x378">
                    </div>
                    <h2>John Smith</h2>
                    <span>Webdesigner</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="team-post">
                    <div class="team-gal">
                        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x378">
                    </div>
                    <h2>Mike Smith</h2>
                    <span>Founder of a Company</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="team-post">
                    <div class="team-gal">
                        <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/300x378">
                    </div>
                    <h2>Donald Smith</h2>
                    <span>Development</span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Vimos que a cada `<li>` que se repete uma nova "página" é gerada para o slider, ou seja, na estrutura ela precisa tratar que a cada um número X de registros ele gere um `<li>`, algo do tipo.

Comment: Posta teu código(php) que você tentou, e assim, poderemos te auxiliar.
Assim parece mais uma pergunta do tipo, "faz pra mim".

Comment: De onde vem o conteudo dessas `h2` e `span`? as imagens são todas iguais, esse conteudo também é diferente a cada `team-post`? (o seu link não funciona para mim...)

Comment: Esclareça seu problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes para destacar exatamente o que precisa. Do modo como está escrito aqui, é difícil saber exatamente o que você está perguntando. Consulte a página Como perguntar para obter ajuda no esclarecimento desta pergunta.

Comment: Basicamente o que ele quer é, olhando a estrutura acima, que a cada 3 divs elas fiquem separadas por uma li para poder chegar no resultado do slide que ele colocou como modelo.

Comment: Sim, entendemos o que ele quer, o problema é exatamente este.
Além que de querer uma resposta pronta, sem ter trabalho, não postou nem os detalhes para podermos ajudar a dar uma resposta, a sua resposta por exemplo, seria completa se ele informasse corretamente, os dados do banco, como está o php dele, etc.
O SOpt ou SOen, são totalmente contra fornecer trabalho pronto, não somos uma comunidade de programação gratuita.

Comment: @MarceloAymone concordo contigo, ta muito vago a pergunta.

Comment: Eu tenho o código php, apenas não consigo mais editar a pergunta pois colocaram em suspensão. O que quero é muito simples e o @DiegoVieira entendeu corretamente, a estrutura html é um modelo mas obviamente em php as imagens e textos vêm do banco. Acredito que a pergunta foi muito simples e de fácil entendimento mas, tenho o código php, e não foi uma pergunta do tipo "faz pra mim", foi do tipo, colaborem com sugestões por favor.

Comment: Aí se encaixaria em outro motivo para suspender a pergunta, por ser baseada em opiniões.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou mantendo a mesma estrutura de código que você usou, onde o php e html estão misturados, para resolver essa questão você pode usar o operador % nessa situação ele vai verificar se já foram processados 3 registros, para isso ele vai dividir a variável $i por 3 e verificar se o resto é 0, quando o resto é 0 significa que o número é múltiplo, pois conseguiu executar uma divisão exata, no seu caso especifico. Isso vai acontecer a cada três registros ou quanto o contador for 0 (0 dividido por qualquer número é 0, portanto divisão exata).

```
<?php

    $i=0; // Essa variável será usada como contador, vai permitir saber quantos registros foram processados
?>

<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
        <div class="row">
            <?php 
                while($rowFotoEmpresa = $fotosEmpresa->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

                // Essa é a parte responsável por fazer com que a cada 3 registros gere um novo li, o zero também é um múltiplo, mas temos que remove-lo do contrário ele irá criar um li sem nenhum registro 
                if($i % 3 == 0 && $i != 0){
            ?>
            </li>
            <li>
            <?php
                } // Essa parte é responsável por encerrar a verificação do contador
                $i++; // Aqui é incrementado o contador, para informar que um novo registro foi processado
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="team-post">
                    <div class="team-gal">
                        <a href="administracao/imagens/quemsomos/imgG/<?php echo $rowFotoEmpresa->NomeImg; ?>" class="zoom">
                            <img alt="" src="administracao/imagens/quemsomos/<?php echo $rowFotoEmpresa->NomeImg; ?>">                          
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>  
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

A cada 3 registros processados ele vai incluir uma tag para fechar a li atual e irá abrir uma nova tag li. Qualquer dúvida deixa um comentário.

> Uma dica que não tem a ver diretamente com o post, tente começar a
>   separar as camadas, separar o php do HTML, usar [MVC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVC). Existem
>   frameworks para Template como o [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) e até [classes com php puro
>   para quem quer usar apenas código nativo](http://raelcunha.com/template.php), isso torna o código mais
>   limpo, mais fácil de ler e de dar manutenção além de ser uma forma
>   mais padronizada de trabalhar. Se quiser ver mais a fundo sobre
>   frameworks veja o [Symfony](http://symfony.com/), [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/) e para [ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) o Doctrine, existem outros, esses são apenas alguns exemplos

Comment: Perfeito, não havia pensado nisto tão simples e prático. Obrigado. o `;` no fechamento do `while` é algum erro? Testei com/sem ele, acaba por não influenciar em nada.

Comment: @TiagoBoeing <?php }; ?> nesse caso o ; não é necessário, foi um erro na hora de transcrever o código. pode ficar apenas <?php } ?>

Comment: Sem problemas, até ia editar a resposta retirando o `;` mas achei que poderia ter algum motivo especial. Vou dar uma olhada nessa sua sugestão, achei interessante.